# Transformed image won't stay visible when the mouse is hovering but not moving?

Tags: html, css, transform

I have my class page [here](http://cis2.oc.ctc.edu/class/pb155.summer17/joshuahemphill/CSS155/BoC/BoC2/classic_rides.htm), where I apply a 3d transform with CSS to pictures to enlarge them with a transition. The problem comes when I hover and it is supposed to be finished with the transition it just disappears unless the mouse moves while still hovering.

I've already tried these things to make sure there's no flickering:

```
   transform: translateZ(0);
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

and

```
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
```

But nothing's fixed it.

Comment: I've looked at your code, you don't need to set transform3D and scale 3D, just use transform and scale. so your image doesn't hide when hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redefine your CSS into:

```
div.regionarticle figure:hover, div.regionarticle figure:active {
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
  transform: translate3d(-180px, 80px, 0px) scale(2, 2);
}
```

You currently have scale3d(2, 2, 0) but that [doesn't exist](http://caniuse.com/#search=scale3d).

Answer (score 0):

The CSS `:hover` can only word while the mouse is still hovering the element, this how it works.

If you want the enlargement start by hover and continue to the end regardless of the mouse position, you can use **CSS Animation.**